# Java Pdf Generating and Download

Tags: java, arrays, pdf, itext

```
public void print()  {

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(ATTACHMENT,  "-normal"));
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
        document.open();

        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, ISO_8859_9, true);
        BaseFont baseBoldFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, ISO_8859_9, true);
        Font font11 = new Font(baseFont, 11);

        document.add(new Paragraph(seciliListeElemani.getOgrno() + " " +
                seciliListeElemani.getAd() + " " + seciliListeElemani.getSoyad() + " Mezun Olabilir!!!!", font11));


        document.close();

        response.setContentLength(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(servletOutputStream);
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();


    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new OrgunException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new OrgunException(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I wrote this code to print a pdf file. When I click my button on my web application, nothing happens. no error messages. It looks like method successfully completed when I debug. But just waiting and waiting no pdf no downloading. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: learn to use a debugger; or add *trace* statements. When you cant observe what your code is doing - then change it to be observable!

Comment: The one answer is correct: this is one really poor method. It starts with the name that doesn't say **anything** about what this method will be doing; and is then followed by all kinds of violations of clean code rules. That is the thing: bugs hide in badly written code.

Comment: Debug your code. Run it locally, and write it to a file. Does that work? If so, something is going wrong that is not related to pdf generation. Use wireshark to see what content is actually being sent over the network.

Comment: @GhostCat method will print a pdf file? how does it say anything to you? I want a file with a sentence in it.Sorry you are just criticizing but no help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The method is called *print*. What the method does is: connect to a **remote** service. Creating a document. Sending that document to the remote service. I would call that method: `sendToServer()` ... and I would already pass the fully created documented ... "print" implies printing. Your method does much more.

Comment: So the problem is the method's name is print and it does do more job? you can consider it "sendToServer".

Comment: Creating the PDF document should be a separate method, so you can test that separately. Each method should have one single responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was the xhtml side.

```
<p:commandButton value="print" actionListener="#{bean.print}" 
  rendered="#{bean.seciliListeElemani.durum_id==5}"></p:commandButton>
```

I added

```
ajax="false"
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that some output stream or writer needs to have `close()` called on it.

I would suggest you separate the different concerns, so that you can debug them more easily and narrow in on the problem. E.g. make the generation of the PDF independent of servlets / Faces. This is good programming practice anyway.

Comment: Such things should go as comment. It's a good comment though.